# How to improve the loading of xml inside my custom wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin which is using an xml to populate 3 custom columns. I have the following which is working 3 times and is loading 3 times the same xml.

```
function read_parse_xml1($product_sku)
{   
  $url = 'http://127.0.0.1/example/bf_shop.xml';
  $xml = file_get_contents($url);
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

  foreach($xml as $x) {
    $sku = $x->sku;
    $bfsku = $x->bf_sku;
    $suppliersku = $x->supplier_sku;
        $price = $x->price;
    $availability = $x->availability;
    $costnovat = $x->cost_no_vat;
    $minprice = $x->min_price;

    if($sku==$product_sku)
        {
        echo '<div id="_supprice-' . $post_id . '">' . number_format( (float)$price,2) . € .  '</div>';

      }     
   }    
}
```

I want the part of

```
$url = 'http://127.0.0.1/example/bf_shop.xml';
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

**to be used and loaded once** but I dont know in which position in my plugin to place it.

Answer (score 0):

define the load outside of the function load there xml and in the function only process the results

```
function read_parse_xml1($product_sku, $xml)
{   
      foreach($xml as $x) {
        $sku = $x->sku;
        $bfsku = $x->bf_sku;
        $suppliersku = $x->supplier_sku;
            $price = $x->price;
        $availability = $x->availability;
        $costnovat = $x->cost_no_vat;
        $minprice = $x->min_price;

        if($sku==$product_sku)
            {
            echo '<div id="_supprice-' . $post_id . '">' . number_format( (float)$price,2) . € .  '</div>';

          }     
       }    
    }
```

Usage:

```
 $url = 'http://127.0.0.1/example/bf_shop.xml';
 $xml = file_get_contents($url);
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);  
 read_parse_xml1($product_sku, $xml);
```

Comment: Yes but where should I copied it to be loaded once?

Comment: check it my anather answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52328568/10309058

Comment: I run inside my php global $xml;
$url = 'http://127.0.0.1/example/bf_shop.xml';
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml); and call $xml in the function named read_parse_xml($product_sku, $xml) but an error comes up Invalid argument supplied for foreach

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the global context for such purposes to decide how to implement

```
function read_parse_xml1($product_sku)
    {   
      global $xml;
      if (empty($xml)){
         $url = 'http://127.0.0.1/example/bf_shop.xml';
         $xml = file_get_contents($url);
         $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
      }
      foreach($xml as $x) {
        $sku = $x->sku;
        $bfsku = $x->bf_sku;
        $suppliersku = $x->supplier_sku;
            $price = $x->price;
        $availability = $x->availability;
        $costnovat = $x->cost_no_vat;
        $minprice = $x->min_price;

        if($sku==$product_sku)
            {
            echo '<div id="_supprice-' . $post_id . '">' . number_format( (float)$price,2) . € .  '</div>';

          }     
       }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the above

```
//READ XML
global $xml;    
$url = 'http://127.0.0.1/example/bf_shop.xml';
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

function read_parse_xml1($product_sku, $xml)
{
  **global $xml;** 

  foreach($xml as $x) {
  $sku = $x->sku;
  $bfsku = $x->bf_sku;
  $suppliersku = $x->supplier_sku;
      $price = $x->price;
  $availability = $x->availability;
  $costnovat = $x->cost_no_vat;
  $minprice = $x->min_price;

  if($sku==$product_sku)
      {
        echo '<div id="_supprice-' . $post_id . '">' . number_format( (float)$price,2) . € .  '</div>';

      }     
}
}
```